# How to add a custom column to Company admin Grid with filtering and sorting options

Tags: magento2

I want to add a column 'company_seller_name' which is present in database custom table "abc_company" to Company Grid. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Shweta Please check following link for [enter link description here](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/add-custom-column-customer-grid-magento-2/)

Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your solution. What changes will be applicable in your code for "company" grid? The link you shared is for customer grid.

Comment: Also , just like the customer  grid uses "customer_grid_flat" table , what table does company grid use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you Please check this below link

**https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/?unapproved=885&moderation-hash=bc29bcc57b29cf44a86bd104cf3b1374#comment-885**

And after you change you code run

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

And any query let me know.

Thanks ...

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your solution. What changes will be applicable in your code for "company" grid? The link you shared is for order grid

Comment: which are you want to show???

Comment: Just like the order grid uses "sales_order_grid" table , what table does company grid use?

Comment: first i kindly suggest read above link. And Other for table you create custom table  name is `company_grid`

Comment: I wanted to know what table does magento uses by default to load "company admin grid" as in which table's collection is loaded for company grid. I have a custom table named "abc_company" . I want to add join column  "company_seller_name" to the collection table . hence wanted to know what tabel should I put

Comment: In step 5 of the tutorial shared - 

`<?php
namespace Codextblog\Ordercolumn\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order;
class Grid
{
    public static $table = 'sales_order_grid';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'custom_order';
   ...`

In this code snippet what should  be the value of $table for company admin grid

Comment: $table value is your default table value

Comment: Hey, I tried with the tutorial. I created the plugin as mentioned . Getting the following error -  
In PluginList.php line 182:
Plugin class Shweta\AbcCompany\Model\Plugin\Company\Grid doesn't exist.
Can you help?

Comment: you run all commands